# Sum column query result in a single field, rather than a separate column

Tags: sql, sum

I have a query, which displays Oracle database datafiles free space above high-water mark and I want to have a field at the end where it says "Total" and the sum of column "FreeSize(Mb)". I was able to do this only in a separate column like below:

```
sum( (bytes/1024/1024) - ceil( (nvl(hwm,1)* (size_db_block))/1024/1024 ) ) OVER() "Total"
```

How can I display this in just a single field? Thanks.

```
SELECT 'alter database datafile '''||file_name||''' resize '|| 
    DECODE(trunc(ceil( (nvl(hwm,1)*(size_db_block))/1024/1024 ) /10),0 ,10, ceil((nvl(hwm,1)* (size_db_block))/1024/1024 )) ||'M;' "Resize Command", 
    AUTOEXTENSIBLE , bytes/1024/1024 "CurrentSize(Mb)" , 
    ((bytes/1024/1024) - ceil((nvl(hwm,1)* (size_db_block))/1024/1024)) "FreeSize(Mb)", sum((bytes/1024/1024) - ceil((nvl(hwm,1)* (size_db_block))/1024/1024)) OVER() "Total"
FROM dba_data_files a, 
    (SELECT file_id, max(block_id+blocks-1) AS hwm FROM dba_extents GROUP BY file_id) b,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(value) AS size_db_block FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'db_block_size') c
WHERE a.file_id = b.file_id(+) AND AUTOEXTENSIBLE='YES' 
AND ceil(blocks*(c.size_db_block)/1024/1024)- ceil((nvl(hwm,1)*(c.size_db_block))/1024/1024 ) > 10
ORDER BY "FreeSize(Mb)";
```

Current output:

```
Resize Command CurrentSize(Mb) FreeSize(Mb)      Total
------------------------------ ------------ ----------
datafile 1                 830           38        617
datafile 2                 100           65        617
datafile 3                 100           80        617
datafile 4                 100           80        617
datafile 5                 390          354        617
```

But I want it to display:

```
Resize Command CurrentSize(Mb) FreeSize(Mb)
------------------------------ ------------
datafile 1                 830           38
datafile 2                 100           65
datafile 3                 100           80
datafile 4                 100           80
datafile 5                 390          354
                               Total:   617
```

Comment: Could you please clean up that query! It is unreadable.

Comment: Edited. I tried what I could. I have not developed the whole query myself. I am not an sql guru so I don't know what can be "cleaned up".

Comment: What exactly is the issue? are you getting more than one row? do you want to use the numbers returned in a subsequent calculation?

Comment: I have added sample output and needed output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you added as an output is not possible in RDBMS terms. You need a reporting tool to display in that format. If you purely want to display in the tool(SQL+ or toad), what you can do is add an extra line to your output which will hold the summed up value for Free Size(Total Free Size).

```
SELECT 'alter database datafile '''||file_name||''' resize '|| 
    DECODE(trunc(ceil( (nvl(hwm,1)*(size_db_block))/1024/1024 ) /10),0 ,10, ceil((nvl(hwm,1)* (size_db_block))/1024/1024 )) ||'M;' "Resize Command", 
    AUTOEXTENSIBLE , bytes/1024/1024 "CurrentSize(Mb)" , 
    ((bytes/1024/1024) - ceil((nvl(hwm,1)* (size_db_block))/1024/1024)) "FreeSize(Mb)"

FROM dba_data_files a, 
    (SELECT file_id, max(block_id+blocks-1) AS hwm FROM dba_extents GROUP BY file_id) b,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(value) AS size_db_block FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'db_block_size') c
WHERE a.file_id = b.file_id(+) AND AUTOEXTENSIBLE='YES' 
AND ceil(blocks*(c.size_db_block)/1024/1024)- ceil((nvl(hwm,1)*(c.size_db_block))/1024/1024 ) > 10
ORDER BY "FreeSize(Mb)"

UNION 


SELECT 'Total Free Size', AUTOEXTENSIBLE ,
    '', 
    sum((bytes/1024/1024) - ceil((nvl(hwm,1)* (size_db_block))/1024/1024)) OVER() "Total"
FROM dba_data_files a, 
    (SELECT file_id, max(block_id+blocks-1) AS hwm FROM dba_extents GROUP BY file_id) b,
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(value) AS size_db_block FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'db_block_size') c
WHERE a.file_id = b.file_id(+) AND AUTOEXTENSIBLE='YES' 
AND ceil(blocks*(c.size_db_block)/1024/1024)- ceil((nvl(hwm,1)*(c.size_db_block))/1024/1024 ) > 10
ORDER BY "FreeSize(Mb)";
```

Comment: I get error ERROR at line 11: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. I have cleared the empty lines from your code, ";" symbol before "union all" and the comma before the first "from".

Comment: SP2-0042: unknown command "UNION ALL" - rest of line ignored. and displays only the 2nd part of the query. The interesting thing is that if I remove the empty lines the code does not run at all.

Comment: I have replaced `UNION ALL` with `UNION`. Give it one more shot

Comment: Same thing with "Union". Are you sure about the empty lines? I have the feeling they mess up things too.